Error E0433: Failed to Resolve metadata_ir in the Crate Root When Using decl_runtime_apis! Macro
When upgrading polkadot-sdk from v1.2.0 to v1.3.0 I am getting the following compile error.
I am encountering a compile error upgrading polkadot-sdk from v1.2.0 to v1.3.0 . The error message is as follows:
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `metadata_ir` in the crate root
   --> /Users/yatusabes/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/c34bcf7/substrate/primitives/api/src/lib.rs:759:1
    |
759 | / decl_runtime_apis! {
760 | |     /// The `Core` runtime api that every Substrate runtime needs to implement.
761 | |     #[core_trait]
762 | |     #[api_version(4)]
...   |
789 | |     }
790 | | }
    | |_^ could not find `metadata_ir` in the crate root
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro `decl_runtime_apis` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.

What could be causing the metadata_ir module or crate to be missing in the context of the decl_runtime_apis! macro? How can I resolve this issue to successfully compile my project?

Could you share your repo? This is usually caused by an incorrect dependency or toolchain upgrade.

@AurevoirXavier https://github.com/frequency-chain/frequency/pull/1993
